# Python. from dateutil.relativedelta import * works in shell but not in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, python-dateutil

When I go to run

```
from datetime import *; from dateutil.relativedelta import *
```

from a python script I get a error which to me seems to indicate a problem with the module itself.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import *
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dateutil.relativedelta import *
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.0-py3.5.egg\dateutil\relativedelta.py", line 11, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\calendar.py", line 47, in <module>
    class _localized_month:
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\calendar.py", line 49, in _localized_month
    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\calendar.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'
```

This however, does not happen when I use the exact same statement in the python shell, if used in the shell it works perfectly.

I did find that it directly related to relativedelta part of dateutil, as

```
from dateutil import *
```

works fine.

I have tried reinstalling dateutil but thats pretty much it.

Running python 3.5.1 with dateutil 2.0 if it matters.

EDIT: SORRY I'M AN IDIOT, my file was called datetime.py which was what caused the problem.

Comment: the fact that you have a file named `datetime.py` in your working directory is the issue. rename it, don't mask Pythons libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the source file name. I am guessing when python interpreter tries to find datetime module it would search the local directory first and the datetime module would be your source file than the datetime global package. [this post explains more](https://gist.github.com/twolfson/7636887)

Once you would rename your file to say dd.py instead of "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\datetime.py" it should work out.